# Amazon Lex chabot replying with separate messages

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a chatbot using Amazon Lex, and AWS Lambda as the back end. I am trying to do so that when a user asks the chatbot, the chatbot will reply with more than one message. Below is my code.

[image]

Is it possible for the chatbot to reply user with separate messages?

An example of it would be something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use the Responses section to build dynamic, engaging conversations for your bot. You can create one or more message groups for a response. At runtime, Amazon Lex builds a response by selecting one message from each message group.

Look into the **Responses** section from below attached link. [Replying with Separate Messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-manage-prompts.html?shortFooter=true#msg-prompts-response)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Lex does not support this functionality, but you can apply a workaround which I have used.

You can get complete message from Lex, put some delimiter in between the message where you want to split,  and on the client side you can split the message based on the delimiter using javascript. Make sure to give something unique as delimiter.

Comment: then you can have one more function which will post the message using facebook developer api's to the user using user's facebook id